# How do I create a CSV file from database in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, file-io, csv

I have a Sqlite 3 and/or MySQL table named "clients"..

Using python 2.6, How do I create a csv file named Clients100914.csv with headers? 
excel dialect...

The Sql execute: select * only gives table data, but I would like complete table with headers.

How do I create a record set to get table headers. The table headers should come directly from sql not written in python.

```
w = csv.writer(open(Fn,'wb'),dialect='excel')
#w.writelines("header_row")
#Fetch into sqld
w.writerows(sqld)
```

This code leaves me with file open and no headers. Also cant get figure out how to use file as log.

Comment: do you want content of that table put into the file?

Comment: What's wrong with using the `csv` module?

Comment: I need all content of table with date.

Comment: I figured out most of it. still need help with header only from database. I can get data.

Comment: @user428862: What code have you tried? Please post your code. If you need help with "header only from database", you'll need to explain what you mean and show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: csr.execute("select * from.....) get the table data. What Sql execute statement do I use to get headers of a table. Next, w = csv.writer(open("test.csv" ,'wb'),dialect='excel'), how I append the cvs, Do I mutliple writes to the open CSV.  "How can a csv file be used for logging." first add headers, then add data.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
import csv
import sqlite3

from glob import glob; from os.path import expanduser
conn = sqlite3.connect( # open "places.sqlite" from one of the Firefox profiles
    glob(expanduser('~/.mozilla/firefox/*/places.sqlite'))[0]
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from moz_places;")
with open("out.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:  # Python 3 version    
#with open("out.csv", "wb") as csv_file:              # Python 2 version
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description]) # write headers
    csv_writer.writerows(cursor)
```

[PEP 249 (DB API 2.0)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description) has more information about `cursor.description`.

Comment: for row in cursor:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
>csv_writer.writerows(row)

Comment: @user428862: the code should also work with MySQL or Sybase databases. I've updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: you should open your file in text mode

Comment: @glefait, actually no, the documentation suggests using the binary mode. See also revision 7 from the history of the answer.

Comment: I run it on python3 & linux. If I open it as binary file, I need to turn my text values into binary.

Comment: Thanks @CristianCiupitu !

Comment: how to i by pass the id column from the database to be written to csv

Answer (score 8):

Using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) is very straight forward and made for this task.

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open("out.csv", 'w'))
writer.writerow(['name', 'address', 'phone', 'etc'])
writer.writerow(['bob', '2 main st', '703', 'yada'])
writer.writerow(['mary', '3 main st', '704', 'yada'])
```

Creates exactly the format you're expecting.

Comment: Its does not write the headers of the table programatically.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily create it manually, writing a file with a chosen separator. You can also use [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

If it's from database you can alo just use a query from your sqlite client :

```
sqlite <db params> < queryfile.sql > output.csv
```

Which will create a csv file with tab separator.

Comment: Of course, the command `.separator ,` can be used in the commands to sqlite to make the csv file use comma separators.

Comment: Does it escape separators in data?

Answer (score 2):

**How to extract the column headings from an existing table:**

*You don't need to parse an SQL "create table" statement.* This is fortunate, as the "create table" syntax is neither nice nor clean, it is warthog-ugly.

You can use the [`table_info`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) pragma. It gives you useful information about each column in a table, including the name of the column.

Example:

```
>>> #coding: ascii
... import sqlite3
>>>
>>> def get_col_names(cursor, table_name):
...     results = cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(%s);" % table_name)
...     return [row[1] for row in results]
...
>>> def wrong_way(cur, table):
...     import re
...     cur.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name=?;", (table, ))
...     sql = cur.fetchone()[0]
...     column_defs = re.findall("[(](.*)[)]", sql)[0]
...     first_words = (line.split()[0].strip() for line in column_defs.split(','))
...     columns = [word for word in first_words if word.upper() != "CONSTRAINT"]
...     return columns
...
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> _ignored = curs.execute(
...     "create table foo (id integer, name text, [haha gotcha] text);"
...     )
>>> print get_col_names(curs, "foo")
[u'id', u'name', u'haha gotcha']
>>> print wrong_way(curs, "foo")
[u'id', u'name', u'[haha'] <<<<<===== WHOOPS!
>>>
```

Other problems with the now-deleted "parse the create table SQL" answer:

1. Stuffs up with e.g. `create table test (id1 text, id2 int, msg text, primary key(id1, id2))` ... needs to ignore not only `CONSTRAINT`, but also keywords `PRIMARY`, `UNIQUE`, `CHECK` and `FOREIGN` (see the [`create table`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) docs).
2. Needs to specify [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) in case there are newlines in the SQL.
3. In `line.split()[0].strip()` the `strip` is redundant.

Comment: thanks, john.... in code below I had to add only two lines to existing code... Go Python!

Answer (score 2):

This is simple and works fine for me.

Lets say you have already connected to your database table and also got a cursor object. So following on on from that point.

```
import csv
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select * from oders")
m_dict = list(curs.fetchall())

with open("mycsvfile.csv", "wb") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, m_dict[0].keys())
    w.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in m_dict[0].keys()))
    w.writerows(m_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done using pandas and sqlite3. In extension to the answer from Cristian Ciupitu.

```
import sqlite3
from glob import glob; from os.path import expanduser
conn = sqlite3.connect(glob(expanduser('data/clients_data.sqlite'))[0])
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Now use pandas to read the table and write to csv.

```
clients = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM clients' ,conn)
clients.to_csv('data/Clients100914.csv', index=False)
```

This is more direct and works all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for Oracle with Python 3.6 :

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

# Create tns
dsn_tns=cx_Oracle.makedsn('<host>', '<port>', service_name='<service_name>')

# Connect to DB using user, password and tns settings
conn=cx_Oracle.connect(user='<user>', password='<pass>',dsn=dsn_tns)
c=conn.cursor()

#Execute the Query
c.execute("select * from <table>")

# Write results into CSV file
with open("<file>.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in c.description]) # write headers
    csv_writer.writerows(c)
```

Comment: Don't forget to tune `arraysize` and `prefetchrows`, see the cx_Oracle tuning doc: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance

Answer (score -1):

unless i'm missing something, you just want to do something like so...

```
f = open("somefile.csv")
f.writelines("header_row")
```

logic to write lines to file (you may need to organize values and add comms or pipes etc...)

```
f.close()
```

Comment: though Guillaume's answer is more direct.