# Get SQL headers from Numpy Array in python

Tags: python, sql, numpy

With below, I can get the row and col data from SQL:
How would I get the table headers as part of the result set or array.?

```
    top = csr.execute("Select * from bigtop")
    d=list(top)
    a = np.asarray(d, dtype='object')
    print a
```

Just like I asked here:
[How do I create a CSV file from database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710263/how-do-i-create-a-csv-file-from-database-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted the column names as the first line in your array, you would do

```
top = csr.execute("Select * from bigtop")
d=list(top)
a = np.asarray([[x[0] for x in top.description]] + d, dtype='object')
```

and get something like

```
array([[heading1, heading2, heading3, ...],
       [val1, val2, val3, ...],
           ...
           , dtype=object)
```

Comment: but I like lafrasu's idea of putting the heading names into the dtype names, which you can access as `a.dtype.names`. Then you can index the columns by number *or* name in the code.

Answer (score 4):

This is a self contained example that illustrates the general idea. `numpy.recarray` is your friend,

```
from sqlite3 import connect
from numpy import asarray

db = connect(":memory:")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('create table bigtop (a int, b int, c int)')

for v in [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]:
    c.execute('insert into bigtop values (?,?,?)',v)

s = c.execute('select * from bigtop')

h = [(i[0],int) for i in c.description]

# You can also use 'object' for your type
# h = [(i[0],object) for i in c.description]

a = asarray(list(s),dtype=h)

print a['a']
```

gives the first column,

```
[1 4 7]
```

and,

```
print a.dtype
```

gives the name and type of each column,

```
[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4')]
```

alternatively, if you used `object` as your type, you get,

```
[('a', '|O4'), ('b', '|O4'), ('c', '|O4')]
```

Comment: Just as an afterthought, you may want to consider something like [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) or [h5py](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/) if you want to store numeric type data. Specifically if you want `numpy` support.

Comment: @lafrasu. pls read the q again. I want the Sql headers as part of the array. In ur ex. it would a, b, c

Comment: @user428862: I saw you changed the question, however I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're after? Once you have an array you have access to the 'headers' through the array's `dtype` attribute.

Comment: show me: "access to the 'headers' through the array's dtype attribute.". the array is  dtype='object'. I'm after complete table headers and data in one array as a package.

Answer (score 2):

`csr.description` should have the headers

Comment: I think that should be `top.description`, in this case.

Comment: and, how how do i get that data into numpy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "get that into numpy" (it's just the data types, right?), but I think `np.asarray(top.description).T[0]` will do what you want.

Comment: how would i combine the two arrays?