# Reading a SQLite file using Python

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I am working on an assignment where in we were provided a bunch of csv files to work on and extract information . I have succesfuly completed that part. As a bonus question we have 1 SQlite file with a `.db` extension . I wanted to know if any module exists to convert such files to `.csv` or to read them directly ?

In case such a method doesnt exist , ill probably insert the file into a database and use the python `sqlite3` module to extract the data I need.

Comment: here look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710263/how-do-i-create-a-csv-file-from-database-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [sqlite commandline tool](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) to dump table data to CSV.

```
To export an SQLite table (or part of a table) as CSV, simply set the "mode" to "csv" and then run a query to extract the desired rows of the table.

sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .once c:/work/dataout.csv
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tab1;
```

> In the example above, the "*.header on*" line causes column labels to be
>   printed as the first row of output. This means that the first row of
>   the resulting CSV file will contain column labels. If column labels
>   are not desired, set ".header off" instead. (The ".header off" setting
>   is the default and can be omitted if the headers have not been
>   previously turned on.)
>
> The line "*.once FILENAME*" causes all query output to go into the named
>   file instead of being printed on the console. In the example above,
>   that line causes the CSV content to be written into a file named
>   "C:/work/dataout.csv".

http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html